# Maven war packaging, include classes ignores excluded resources

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have the following pom

```
 <project> 

     ....
     <packaging>war</packaging>
     ....
     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>config/**/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

       <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/sass/**</warSourceExcludes>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <webResources>
                         <resource>

                            <directory>src/main/resources/config</directory>

                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
...
</project>
```

As you can see, I package a WAR while my `.class` files are not in my `WEB-INF/classes` folder - they are packaged into a JAR instead.

Now, I am desperately trying to exclude some resources from my JAR - but it does not work. When I run `mvn jar:jar` - the resources are excluded, however when I run `mvn package` the resources are there.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that @user944849 is right - indeed, the war plugin does not use the jar plugin in order to achieve the JAR packaging.

However, his answer gave me a wrong result still as it will simply create 2 jars - one will be with the resources and the other without. The WAR will still use the wrong one.

The correct answer is to use the new maven `resources` tag.

The one that corresponds to my configuration looks as follows

```
    <build>
      .... 
       <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>config/**/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
      ....
     </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the `jar:jar` goal bound to a lifecycle phase.  When you run `jar:jar` from the command line, the exclusions happen fine; when you run `mvn clean package` I suspect `jar:jar` is not executing.  Try binding the goal to a phase:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>config/**/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

FYI, the `archiveClasses` feature of the [war:war plugin goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html) does something similar to what I think you're trying to achieve without requiring a separate plugin config.